# Creating Dictionary from Excel file in IronPython

Tags: python, excel, ironpython

The only main difference between IronPython and Python, is basically I can't use pandas in IronPython.

I have an excel spreadsheet where I want the first column to be the keys, and the second column to be the values for each of the keys.

Is there as simple way to do this?

Comment: Have you looked at the `csv` module?

Comment: Yeah , but the csv returns a list when I use DictRead

Comment: The `csv` module isn't quite as high-level as `pandas`. You need to construct the `dict` yourself. Use `csv.reader` to get 2-lists and build up your dict row by row: `mydict[row[0]] = row[1]`.